# Can Non-EU citizen get France Work permit Visa from Germany (working in Germany)?

Tags: indian-citizens, germany, france, eu, work-permit

I'm holding an Indian passport with valid Work permit for Germany and I don't have an EU blue card.

If I get a job in France, I understand that I have to get the work permit for working in France if I don't have a valid EU blue card.

in this use case, ***Can I get the work permit for France working/living from Germany instead of coming back to India and applying for France work permit?***

or

***do I have to go back India and apply from scratch for France Work permit?***

is it possible to get France work permit living from Germany for non-EU citizens?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Can I get the work permit for France working/living from Germany instead of coming back to India and applying for France work permit?

Likely, yes

The [French Consulate General](https://de.ambafrance.org/Informations-generales-General-information-Allgemeine-Informationen-18132#General-information) in Frankfurt (competent for the whole country) states :

> COMPETENCE OF THE CONSULATE : The consulate is competent to receive your visa application if you have been legally residing in Germany for more than 3 months with a valid German residence permit or German D Visa which must still be valid for at least 1 month (special conditions COVID-19 : click here to read the article)

---

> do I have to go back India and apply from scratch for France Work permit?

If you don't fulfil the above requirements, then yes